# I can install eloquent-sluggable in laravel 5.5 there are some errors

Tags: package, eloquent

I wanted to install eloquent-sluggable but I get this type of error
and my laravel version =5.5 and my php version is 7.0 but I don't know what can I do with this error.
If u know please help me.

My error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - illuminate/support v5.6.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v5.6.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v5.6.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v5.6.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable 4.5.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.2, v5.6.3].
    - Installation request for cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable 4.5 -> satisfiable by cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable[4.5.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


-------
```

I followed the related site but I can solve it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do that. The problem is pretty simple: As the error message says, these packages need at least PHP 7.1.3, while you have PHP 7.0.10 installed:

```
requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement
```

Updating your PHP version would to the trick. How this is done depends on how your development environment is setup.

Comment: thank u for your answer but you know what i did it befor that i shared thid quesion i install it but it didn't work either .
and yes your right the error is very bright but the solution is not
thanks alot.